# xml.modify hashing string

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, xquery

i wrote simple script which hashing value of xml. String is hashing correct but w in xml this string changed only on string consisting of one char '?'.

```
  DECLARE
   @xml        XML,
   @v          NVARCHAR (MAX),
   @hashData   NVARCHAR (MAX);
SET @xml = '<ppl>
  <fname>JOHN</fname>
  <lname>SMITH</lname>
</ppl>';


SET @v = @xml.value ('(/ppl/fname)[1]', 'nvarchar(255)');
SET @hashData = HASHBYTES ('MD5', @v);
PRINT @v + ' ' + @hashData;
DECLARE @SQL   NVARCHAR (MAX)
           =   'set @xml.modify(''replace value of (/ppl/fname/text())[1]
                      with "'
             + @hashData
             + '"
                      '')';

EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @parameters = N'@xml xml output', @xml = @xml OUTPUT ;

SELECT @xml;
```

There is two answers:
One correct: `JOHN 둕羪ꚧ඄Ϥ딴ꬎ`

And second:

```
<ppl><fname>????????</fname><lname>SMITH</lname></ppl>
```

Can You give me some tips how to resolve this problem?

ps. sorry for my poor English, i still working on it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HASHBYTE output type is varbinarty(8000). (see [HASHBYTES (Transact-SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174415%28v=sql.120%29.aspx))

You have to cast it to varchar using either style 1 or 2:

```
Convert(varchar(34), HASHBYTES ('MD5', @v), 1)
```

> output = 0x55B434EDAA7FA7A6840DE40334B50EAB

or

```
Convert(varchar(32), HASHBYTES ('MD5', @v), 2)
```

> output = 55B434EDAA7FA7A6840DE40334B50EAB